# How to Generate XSLT using SSIS

Tags: xml, xslt, ssis

I have an xml script and I want to create\generate xslt for that using ssis.

Thanks,
Ashis

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with XML task, selecting XSLT as operation type:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed answer because the user (or even myself) may not know the steps of creating the XML task using XSLT?